# How does ContentInset work within a ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I know what Content Inset does, it will inset the contentView within the UIScrollView. At this point it seems to add those values to the contentSize meaning I would need to do this:

```
    [__scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)];
    [__scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(__scrollView.frame.size.width - __scrollView.contentInset.left - __scrollView.contentInset.right, 0.0)];
```

But the problem is, after I use contentInset, I don't see the scroll indicators anymore? Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` to be smaller than the size of the scroll view itself. Only if `contentSize` is bigger than the scrollview's `frame' will there be any scroll indicators.

Comment: I debugged the frame of the UIScrollView and the contentSize and this is the result: UIScrollView.frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 367}}; contentSize = {300, 469}; As you can see the contentSize's height is larger then the frame size, although it can scroll to the position it does not show the indicators.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that since you set the height to 0.0 in the code sample that the contentSize.height would be 0. If the content size if bigger than the frame then I can't see what could be wrong. But have you checked that `__scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` is set to YES?

Comment: Yes I even set it to make absolutely sure it does that. I am gonna post the complete code soon as this happens everytime I set the contentInset so perhaps people can help me more quickly on what I am doing wrong.